# TYPO3 render bodytext from class. Errror accessing lib.parseFunc_RTE

Tags: typo3

I have a custom cType for tt_content where the header and bodytext fields from a normal tt_content are reused. The goal is to have a custom tt_content cType that just displays header and bodytext in the normal way. But I need to do it from php and not TS as I will have to process the text before returning it.

I can output header and bodytext as raw text, but I cannot format the bodytext using pi_RTEcssText. Every time I try it fails. Something with no access to parseFunc_RTE.

Any other good ideas on how to output bodytext correctly formatted using custom class (not frontend plugin). I have tried to include tslib and store it in $this->hObj and also tried the normal $this->cObj with same restult

```
require_once(PATH_tslib . 'interfaces/interface.tslib_content_cobjgetsinglehook.php');
require_once(PATH_tslib . 'class.tslib_pibase.php');

class tx_cObj_ogProcessTtContent implements tslib_content_cObjGetSingleHook {
    protected $cObj;

    public function getSingleContentObject($contentObjectName, array $configuration, $TypoScriptKey, tslib_cObj &$parentObject) {

        $this->cObj =& $parentObject;

        // access to pibase
        $this->hObj = new tslib_pibase(); // <-- did try with cObj with same result

        // content from current tt_content element
        $headerOfCE = $this->cObj->data['header'];
        $bodytextOfCE = $this->cObj->data['bodytext'];


        // header
        $content = '<h1>'.$headerOfCE.'</h1>'; // <-- is there a wrap as header func?
        // add bodytext (not possible since no access to lib.parseFunc_RTE)
        $content .= $this->hObj->pi_RTEcssText($bodytextOfCE);

        return $content; 

    }

}
```

Comment: "Something with" is a really bad description. If it doesn't work, we need the exact error, not "something with". It's obvious that "something" doesn't work :-).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the cObject hook for that simple case.

You can register a new plugin in typo3conf/extTables.php (AdditionalConfiguration.php):

```
$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['mycontent'] = array(
    'label' => 'My Content',
);

$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][] = array('My Content', 'mycontent', 'path/to/my_icon.gif');

/* Arrange the fields you want to use in your content element */
$TCA['tt_content']['types']['mycontent'] = array(
    'showitem' => 'CType;;4;;1-1-1, hidden, header, bodytext,
                    --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_tca.xml:pages.tabs.access, starttime, endtime'
);
```

Then you can add your content type to the new content element wizard using Page TSconfig:

```
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems {
    mycontent {
        icon = path/to/my_icon.gif
    }
    common.show := addToList(mycontent)
}

mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements.mycontent {
        icon = path/to/my_icon.gif
        title = My content
        description = The description
        tt_content_defValues {
            CType = mycontent
        }
}
```

And then you need some TypoScript to render the content correctly. If you want to use the rendering from tt_content as a base, use

```
tt_content.mycontent < tt_content.text
```

Then you could e.g. manipulate the rendering of your header:

```
# delete the stdheader
tt_content.mycontent.10 >
tt_content.mycontent.10 = TEXT
tt_content.mycontent.10.field = header
tt_content.mycontent.10.wrap = <h1>|</h1>
```